# Get average marginal effects for multiple models produced in loop

Tags: r, loops, purrr, lm, margins

Here is my example data:

```
date = as.Date(c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05",
                 "2018-01-08")),
X10026 = c(NA, -0.00998786767581905, 0.0138127158236847,
           -0.00955052427703185, 0.000741739716790146),
X10028 = c(NA, 0.0102061855670104, -0.0205122971731809,
           -0.0103146488851844, 0.0631645436361723),
X10032 = c(NA, 0.00130975769482644, 0.0122629169391759,
           0.00492650621870472, 0.0466929197138954),
X93436 = c(NA, -0.0102330515084391, -0.00828999211977932,
           0.00622970567668935, 0.0626382292829057),
mktrf = c(0.0085, 0.0059, 0.0042, 0.0066, 0.0019),
smb = c(0.0036, -0.0039, -0.0026, -0.0034, -0.0016),
hml = c(-0.0022, -0.0021, 0.0024, -0.0026, 7e-04)
)
```

Now, I am trying to run a linear regression on multiple outcome variables. I want to do this with the purr:map function and the broom package. That worked fine after a while. However, now I want to get average marginal effects based on the saved models with ggeffect. ggpredict works, but ggeffect does not. ggpredict holds control variables at their reference catergory, I want average marginal effects holding values constant at their observed values.

here is my attempt:

```
# loop over outcomes; save predicted valies (at reference l)
# loop over outcome variables
sample_data <- sample_data %>% 
  gather(stock, return, starts_with("X")) %>% 
  group_nest(stock) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data,
                     ~lm(formula = "return ~ mktrf + hml + smb",
                         data = .x,
                         na.action = na.exclude)),
        effects = map(model,ggeffect),
         tidy = map(model, broom::tidy),
    glance = map(model, broom::glance),
    augment = map(model, broom::augment)) %>%
  unnest(data)
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
Can't compute marginal effects, 'effects::Effect()' returned an error.

Reason: object '.x' not found
You may try 'ggpredict()' or 'ggemmeans()'.
```

ggeffects works outside the loop, so it must have something to do with the map function. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Your example data doesn't work or match you code

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. Pasted the wrong chunk.

Comment: This probably has to do how the _effects_ or _emmeans_ package work inside such loops. If you use `ggpredict` instead, it works (for me).